# Scanner object keeps expecting input

Tags: java

I have the following code in which a matrix is defined through system input:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        //define size of matrix
        int size = in.nextInt();

        int primeSum = 0;
        int secSum = 0;
        int[] matrix = new int[size*size];

        //create matrix
        for (int i=0; i<size*size;i++) {
            matrix[i] = in.nextInt();
        }

        in.close();

        //sum primary diagonal
        for (int i=0; i < size*size;i += (size + 1)) {
            primeSum = primeSum + matrix[i];
        }

////sum secondary diagonal
//        for (int i=(size - 1); i < size*size; i += (size - 2)) {
//          secSum = secSum + matrix[i];
//        }

        System.out.println(Math.abs(secSum - primeSum));


    }
}
```

The code above works in that it allows the user to define an NxN matrix through inputting N as the size - so in the case size = 2 the user would define 4 matrix elements. However, after commenting back in the code for the secondary diagonal, the scanner object keeps expecting input past 4 integers - I have no idea why this would affect the program as I close the input stream before that block of code is reached.

Comment: Just imagine your example, you are running in an infinite loop: Matrix size = 2. Do you think `i += (size - 2)` will make `i` increment? Note that every size > 2 will work again.

Comment: No but in the case size = 3  and beyond it will

Comment: Yeah but then the condition `i<size*size` will never be met and the loop wont stop

Comment: @KevinEsche gotcha - I think I see the issue now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote a potentially infinite loop. I.e. if size is not greater than 2, then `i` will count down or stay `0`. You should cover these corner cases, then your code will be fine.

As far as I can see, you're emulating a two-dimensional array on a one-dimensional. This is something that's hard to understand and easy to mess up.  You are better off with a two-dimensional array and some nested loops:

```
    int[][] matrix = new int[size][size];

    //create matrix
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<size; j++) {
            matrix[i][j] = in.nextInt();
        }
    }
    // and so on...
```

Answer (score 1):

Your this part of code:

```
 for (int i=0; i<size*size;i++) {
       matrix[i] = in.nextInt();
 }
```

calls the method `nextInt` which demands for input as long as the array is filled.